# Session and FormsAuthentication in MVC3 access control

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3, session

I am using SESSION for storing user data, thus avoiding unnecessary access to the database. However, each access controller, data FormsAuthentication are renewed and data SESSION no.

What better way to get around this problem?
Put the lives of the great SESSION, or make a Base Controller or each called a ActionResult renew the life of SESSION.

Detail, SESSION I use this to mount a header of my pages.

This code, create SESSION.

```
public static void UsuarioLogar(string login)
{
    CustomMembershipUser usuario = new CustomMembershipUser();
    using (var dbUser = new ERPContext())
    {
        var dados = (from u in dbUser.Usuario
                     where u.Login == login
                     select new
                     {
                         Nome = u.Nome,
                         UsuarioID = u.UsuarioID,
                         EmpresaID = u.EmpresaID,
                         EmpresaLogada = u.Empresa,
                         PessoaLogada = u.PessoaLogada
                     }).FirstOrDefault();

        if (dados != null)
        {
            usuario.UsuarioID = dados.UsuarioID;
            usuario.Nome = dados.Nome;
            usuario.EmpresaID = dados.EmpresaID;

            usuario.EmpresaLogada = dados.EmpresaLogada;
            usuario.PessoaLogada = dados.PessoaLogada;

            if (usuario.PessoaLogada != null)
                usuario.Acesso = "Restrito";
            else
                usuario.Acesso = "Full";
            HttpContext.Current.Session["usuarioLogado"] = usuario;
        }
        else
        {
            HttpContext.Current.Session["usuario"] = null;
            FormsAuthentication.SignOut();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I take it english is not your first language but the question is not understandable.  Are you have trouble with session ending quickly or not extending?

Comment: My problem is that the FormsAuthentication is renewed at each access to a controller and not SESSION, exhaling her. I am needing to know the best way to keep alive every access to a Controller SESSION.

Answer (score 0):

I would avoid Session, especially when using MVC - it isn't a good fit with the web.

One alternative would be to use [IIdentity](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.principal.iidentity%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) and set the details in the [Application_AuthenticateRequest](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httpapplication.authenticaterequest%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) method.